# What would happen if a body possessing a charge $(-1) \text { e}$ is brought into contact with an electrically neutral object?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge

Let's say that a body $A$ possesses a charge of $-1 \text{ e}$ (electron) and another body $B$ is electrically neutral (has a charge of $0 \text{ e}$). Now, if we bring any two objects in contact, from an electricity point of view, there would be an exchange of electrons so that both the objects posses a charge of the same magnitude after the contact. If one of the objects has a charge of $x \text{ units}$ and another one has a charge of $y \text { units}$, the magnitude of charge possessed by each one of them post-contact will be $\dfrac{x+y}{2} \text { units}$.In the case in my question, $x$ is $-1 \text{ e}$ and $y$ is $0 \text{ e}$, so $\dfrac{x+y}{2}$ is equal to $\dfrac{-1}{\text{ }2} \text{ e}$, which is not possible as the smallest magnitude of charge that exists independently is $\pm 1 \text{ e}$, the magnitude of charge possessed by a single *electron* or *proton*...

And looking from a general point of view too, $A$ has one *electron* more than it has *protons*, hence the charge of $-1 \text{ e}$, and $B$ is electrically neutral, so the minimum amount of charge that can be transferred from $A$ to $B$ will be $1  \text{ e}$, which will cause $B$ to possess a charge of $-1 \text{ e}$ and $A$ to be electrically neutral, which just reverses the scenario.

So, what would happen in this case? Would that one electron not flow? Or would it keep flowing infinitely? Or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to note:

> Let's say that a body $A$ possesses a charge of $-1 \text{ e}$ (electron) and another body $B$ is electrically neutral (has a charge of $0 \text{ e}$).

No object can have $0$ electrical charge. A charged object has excess electrons than protons, or vice versa.

> If one of the objects has a charge of $x \text{ units}$ and another one has a charge of $y \text { units}$, the magnitude of charge possessed by each one of them post-contact will be $\dfrac{x+y}{2} \text { units}$.

This is not true, in general. The transfer of charge from one body to another (charged or uncharged) is based on the minimisation of the electrical potential energy of the system. That can result in an uneven distribution of charge among the two bodies. Even then, we need to consider the other chemical factors and electronic configuration of the two objects. An example can be one involving an inert gas. However charged the other object maybe, the inert gas has zero electron affinity.

> So, what would happen in this case? Would that one electron not flow? Or would it keep flowing infinitely? Or something else?

Usually, if we limit our observations to metals and insulator only, then the excess electrons will get distributed among the 2 bodies in such a way that the electrical potential energy of the system is minimised. In this case, also, the same thing will hold. So finally it depends on the electrical nature and electronic configuration of A and B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `No object can have 0 electrical charge`. Neutral objects can, right? And I do mention that $B$ is electrically neutral. And also, I would really appreciate it if you can explain the statement :`"Finally it depends on the electrical nature and electronic configuration of A and B"`.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu If you read again, you will see I meant that neutral objects have $\textbf{net}$ charge zero. But that doesn't mean they don't have any electrons at all. It means they have equal number of electrons and protons.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Regarding your second query, it is similar to the inert gas case. So it depends on what A and B are. Is A a halogen like fluorine, chlorine, bromine? Is B something like sodium? Or are they like Carbon? OR maybe Argon or Neon? See, different electronic configurations (which means how many electrons they possess and how many of them are actually free electrons) have different electron affinities (how much willing they are energetically to attract electrons towards themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is the whole transfer scenario depends on electron affinity values of the materials A and B. Just like SchrodingersCat elaborated. Different materials will have different 'attractions' for electron. In this case, if B has a greater electron affinity than A, the transfer is plausible of course. So now B will become a 1- ion while A will become neutral molecule minimizing the electrical potential energy of the configuration. But all the aforementioned depends on what A is - the previous description holds only for matter made up of atoms or molecules. When we talk about charges transferring we always have a charge carrier that ***carries*** the charge from atom/molecule to another. Usually the charge carrier is just the electron. So when we talk about A being neutral here, we mean A possesses 0 net charge which is, of course, completely plausible. However, if A is an electron, A ***itself*** will enter B's electron configuration giving it a charge of -1 but you have to understand A does NOT lose its charge - it is the charge carrier and is the particle that *gives* B the negative charge.